# Getting information to a Plug router from the Cowboy startup call

Tags: elixir, cowboy

I'm looking for some way to get a string from my Cowboy startup call...

```
token = RandomString.generate()
Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http MyRouter, []
```

To the code used in the router:

```
get "/webhook/:token" do
  if token == [what I generated earlier] do
    # handle request
  end
end
```

---

To be more specific: I'm working on a webhook server. I want to:

1. Generate a secret token on server startup;
2. Send that token to an API server which will use it for future requests to my server;
3. *The bit I'm struggling with:* Have the server compare the token supplied in requests to the generated token, and ensure a match to allow the request.

I can't see anything in either of the options arguments to `Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http` that would allow me to get user data to the router.

How can I get the token from the function that starts cowboy to the router, so I can enforce the authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a named ETS table to store the token. During startup, do:

```
:ets.new(:configuration, [:named_table, :set, :protected])
:ets.insert(:configuration, {:token, token})
```

Then, when you need to fetch the token later:

```
[token: token] = :ets.lookup(:configuration, :token)
```

Also see

- http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/ets.html
- http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html